# How to set a filter to get "Modbus/TCP" data in SharpPcap?

Tags: c#, winpcap, sharppcap

I am using SharpPcap.

In Wireshark, I can set the filter as `mbtcp` or `modbus and tcp`, and it works well.

In SharpPcap, if the filter is set as `mbtcp` or `modbus and tcp`, an exception

```
SharpPcap.PcapException:“syntax error”
```

will happen. I have make sure I type the string correctly.

So, how to set the filter to get all Modbus/TCP data?

Comment: I use "tcp port 502" to realize my requirement now. But I want a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want a solution

You found a solution - "tcp port 502".

> In Wireshark, I can set the filter as mbtcp or modbus and tcp, and it works well.

That's a Wireshark packet-matching expression, usually called a "display filter" (although it can also be used, for example, in coloring rules, which aren't filters).  Those are processed by code in Wireshark, which is based on Wireshark's packet-dissection engine, so they work in programs that use that engine (such as Wireshark and TShark) and won't work in code that doesn't have Wireshark's packet-dissection engine.

> In SharpPcap, if the filter is set as mbtcp or modbus and tcp, an exception
>
> ```
> SharpPcap.PcapException:“syntax error”
> ```
>
> will happen. I have make sure I type the string correctly.

SharpPcap *isn't* code that has Wireshark's packet-dissection engine, it's a library that's a C# wrapper for libpcap.  This means that, in SharpPcap, that filter is a *libpcap* filter, which is written in [libcpap filter syntax](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html), which is not the same as Wireshark packet-matching expression syntax, and is not as powerful as that syntax.

There is no simple way to incorporate Wireshark's packet-dissection engine into programs, so your best choice here is either 1) to use Wireshark rather than your program or 2) to use "tcp port 502" as your filter.